# How can I determine which PHP Form class a displaying Form belongs to?

Tags: forms

If I want to modify a form, should I use hook_civicrm_buildForm? This function requires a formName argument, so how can I identify the FormName or Form ID of the form I'm currently viewing on the site? Does CiviCRM have built-in debugging tools for this purpose, or do I need to use a third-party extension like Devel for Drupal?

I would greatly appreciate any assistance that anyone can provide. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, to modify the form you can hook_civicrm_buildForm. If you print the $formName you should be able to see formname on screen.

I normally use Civi build in function for debuggings

1. To print on screen - CRM_Core_Error::debug('$formname', $formName);
2. To print in Civi logs - CRM_Core_Error::debug_va('$formname', $formName);
3. Backtrace to show screen -  CRM_Core_Error::backtrace();
4. Backtrace in log -  CRM_Core_Error::backtrace('show', TRUE);

Comment: Thanks for your answer, should I run these debug codes inside the custom module directory?

Comment: Yes, put exit; statement

Answer (score 1):

[Appending &smartyDebug=1](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/tools/debugging/#using-url-parameters) to the URL will pop out a window that contains a lot of info including formName and formClass.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I would like to know how to use the solution provided if the form is an AJAX form. I tried adding '&smartyDebug=1', but it only shows the information before the form is loaded and appears.

Comment: Depends on what you're looking at. Something SearchKit-based would be quite different from Mailings, for example.